# How to call onCreateView of a separate Fragement Class in MainActivity Class?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, main-activity

Please Help me. I want to show Fragment class List into MainActivity. I try in main activity new (); but It show blank page, but when I put all data into mainActivity and run then it show list of data. 
Actually, I want to learn how to get this method from other class into mainactivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        new ForecastFragment();
    }


//----------------- A Separate ForecastFragment Class ------ 

public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment() {

    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] data={
                "Sunday",
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday"
        };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_forecast,container,false);

        ListView listView =(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        List<String> listData=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),R.layout.list_item_forecast,R.id.textView,listData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainActivity layout file` , you should have a `FrameLayout` which will contain your fragment.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Now in your `MainActivity` class, you'll instantiate your Fragment like this :

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new ForecastFragment(), ForecastFragment.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
```

Your can instantiate your fragment as above at any point in your `MainActivity` class. In your case, you should do that in `MainActivity's onCreate()`

If you don't want to use Android support version library, you can use :

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, new ForecastFragment(), ForecastFragment.class.getSimpleName().commit();
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Shadab Ansari, After ForecastFragment.getClass change into ForecastFragment.class and adding .cummit(); than it works.  Now it works. :)

Comment: Oh yes, I missed adding commit(). Thanks for noticing it. Edited my answer for future.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just instantiate a fragment by calling new, you have to add it to the stack:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment(), "fragment_tag")
    .commit();
```

Where R.id.container is the container in your layout (usually a FrameLayou) to hold your fragment.

Comment: Thanks It works. here is my code : getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new ForecastFragment(), ForecastFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                .commit();